# Phaser 3: some animations stopped playing suddenly

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

I'm using Phaser 3.11

I have animations for my sprite (walk animations) as well as an animated title that displays to prompt the player to click (just a trick so ensure the audio will play properly). I also have an animation for a cat swishing its tail.

All three were working fine the entire duration of the project. But SUDDENLY, after I added a new sprite, 2/3 of the above animations stopped working (the walk cycle, and the title). The cat's tail still animates, weirdly. I of course put the old sprite back in because that's the only thing I'd changed, but nope, this bug seems to be permanent.

code below:

in preload:

```
this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/runner/kel2.png', {
    frameWidth: 16,
    frameHeight: 28,
  });
  this.load.spritesheet('buffy', 'assets/runner/buffy.png', {
    frameWidth: 43,
    frameHeight: 32,
  });
  this.load.spritesheet('startText', 'assets/runner/clickToStart2.png', {
    frameWidth: 351,
    frameHeight: 250,
  });
```

in create:

```
player = this.physics.add.sprite(playerStart, 260, 'dude').setScale(1.3)

this.anims.create({
    //animations created are available globally, belonging to the game objects themselves!
    key: 'left',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 3 }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1,
    //use frames 0,1,2,3 at 10 fps, and -1 repeat tells it to loop
  });

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'turn',
    frames: [{ key: 'dude', frame: 4 }],
    frameRate: 20,
  });

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'right',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 5, end: 8 }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1,
  });


buffy = this.physics.add.sprite(3170, 270, 'buffy');
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'curl',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('buffy', { start: 0, end: 1 }),
    frameRate: 2,
    repeat: -1,
  });


startText = this.physics.add.staticSprite(240, 150, 'startText');
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'clickToStart',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('startText', { start: 0, end: 1 }),
    frameRate: 2,
    repeat: -1,
  });
```

in update:

```
if (cursors.left.isDown) {
      player.setVelocityX(-100);
      player.anims.play('left', true);
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
      player.setVelocityX(100);
      player.anims.play('right', true);
    } else {
      player.setVelocityX(0);
      player.anims.play('turn');
    }

    buffy.anims.play('curl', true);
    startText.anims.play('clickToStart', true);
```

again, the second to last thing in update (buffy.anims.play) is working fine
Everything else however, is stuck on one frame. Anyone ever encountered something like this before? I've been googling for over an hour now to no avail.

[cat spritesheet (the working one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81rbK.png)

[player spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npPBz.png)

[title screen spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMgie.png)

EDIT TO ADD:

I fixed the title screen sprite. That one wasn't a glitch, I just had accidentally enclosed it in an if block that was dependant on whether the game had started yet. Took it out, all is well now. BUT the sprite walk animations still don't work. Still no ideas.

EDIT 2:

After some digging around with console.logs I've diagnosed that:

a) the program is indeed NOT CYCLING through the frames in its frame array (turning left or right, the current frame is only either 0 or 5, but if I checkout a previous commit where it worked, it goes 0,1,2,3 and 5,6,7,8 respectively)

b) the program HAS ACCESS to the frame array. aka generateFrameNumbers is working. if I console.log to getTotalFrames() on the sprite and then go left or right it gives 4 for each, respectively (and 1 for the facing forward, as it should).

c) if I manually set the starting frame, it will change. It'll still be frozen, but it'll be frozen on straight legs vs walking legs, depending on which frame I set as the start point in anims.play. So again, it has all the frames, it's just not cycling.

Comment: You should report this bug if it's a bug on the Phaser repo in GitHub